# Crear Stored procedure en Mysql con WorkBench con 2 o mas variables (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench

Buenas noches a todos.

Antes que nada, aclaro que soy nuevo en *Mysql* y al querer pasar una estructura de base de datos de *MS SQL* a *Mysql* me encuentro con una serie de diferencias que estoy intentando resolver pero ya no encuentro la solución.

Mi problema es el siguiente, quiero crear el siguiente SP:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_NPC` (
    in P_IdP int, 
    in P_CG double(19,4), 
    in P_FV datetime, 
    in P_Usuario varchar(50)
)
BEGIN

declare @V_VC as double,
            @V_UL as double,
            @V_Estado varchar(1) = 'A'

set V_VC = Select sum(VwC.PC * pc.C) 
    from St_P P 
        inner join St_PC Pc on pc.IdPR = p.IdP
        inner join St_P PcDesc on PcDesc.IdP = pc.IdPI
        inner join Vw_LMPCV VwC on VwC.IdP = pc.IdPI
    where p.IdP = P_IdP

set @V_UL = Select IfNull(max(NL),0) + 1 from St_PS where IdP = P_IdP

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[St_PS]
           ([IdP]
           ,[NL]
           ,[VL]
           ,[CC]
           ,[CoC]
           ,[US]
           ,[Estado]
           ,[FecAlta]
           ,[Usuario])
     VALUES
           (@P_IdP
           ,@V_UL
           ,@P_FV
           ,@P_CG
           ,@V_VC
           ,@P_CG
           ,@V_Estado
           ,GETDATE()
           ,@P_Usuario)

END
```

Básicamente el problema me lo remarca donde empiezo a declarar las variables después del `begin`, pero no me permite ver mas allá de lo que indica el problema, ¿me podrán ayudar a determinar donde me estoy equivocando para saber por que me esta dando error?

Saludos.

Comment: Por un lado debo recordarte que los corchetes son para escapar el nombre de campos y tablas, en MySQL se usan comillas invertidas. Puedes omitir los corchetes. Además, no estás usando un separador de línea al terminar cada `declare` o `set` (e incluso el `INSERT INTO`). ¿Podrías poner lo que estás intentando hacer en MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explicación

Tienes que tener en cuenta las siguientes diferencias:

- Necesitas finalizar cada instrucción con un delimitador (por defecto `;`).
- El valor por defecto en MySQL se indica con `DEFAULT` y no con una asignación.
- Las variables no tienen que estar precedidas de un `@` al declararlas.
- La asignación de un resultado de `SELECT` a una variable se realiza mediante un `INTO` y no un `SET`.

### Solución

Tu procedimiento almacenado en MySQL debería escribirse así:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_NPC`(
  IN P_IdP INT,
  IN P_CG DOUBLE(19,4),
  IN P_FV DATETIME,
  IN P_Usuario VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_VC DOUBLE;
  DECLARE V_UL DOUBLE;
  DECLARE V_Estado VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'A';

  SELECT SUM(VwC.PC * pc.C) INTO V_VC
    from St_P P 
        inner join St_PC Pc on pc.IdPR = p.IdP
        inner join St_P PcDesc on PcDesc.IdP = pc.IdPI
        inner join Vw_LMPCV VwC on VwC.IdP = pc.IdPI
    where p.IdP = P_IdP;

  SELECT IfNull(max(NL),0) + 1 INTO V_UL from St_PS where IdP = P_IdP;

    INSERT INTO St_PS
           (IdP
           ,NL
           ,VL
           ,CC
           ,CoC
           ,US
           ,Estado
           ,FecAlta
           ,Usuario)
     VALUES
           (P_IdP
           ,V_UL
           ,P_FV
           ,P_CG
           ,V_VC
           ,P_CG
           ,V_Estado
           ,GETDATE()
           ,P_Usuario);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

### Ejemplos paso a paso:

Tu declaración:

```
DECLARE @V_Estado varchar(1) = 'A'
```

Debe hacerse así:

```
DECLARE V_Estado varchar(1) DEFAULT 'A'
```

Tu asignación:

```
set @V_UL = Select IfNull(max(NL),0) + 1 from St_PS where IdP = P_IdP
```

Debe hacerse así:

```
SELECT IfNull(max(NL),0) + 1 INTO V_UL from St_PS where IdP = P_IdP
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Oscar! fue de mucha ayuda y nuevo aprendisaje para mi, muchas gracias!!

con las correcciones que me comentaste funcionó correctamente!